# autoload.php class not found

Tags: php, oop

I'm usually programming in java language , but now i have to know the oop php. I made a sample project for myself for practice , but it doesn't work. I need some help what did i do wrong. Here is my 3 php files.

Index.php

```
<?php

require_once 'classes/Autoload.php';

$person = new Person();
$person->setName('asd');
$person->getName();?>
```

Person.php

```
<?php
    class Person{

        private $name ;
        private $age



        public function setName($name){
            $this->name = $name;

        }


        public function getName(){
            echo $this->name."<br>";

        }


    }
```

and here is the autoload.php

```
<?
function _autoload($class){
        include 'classes/'.$class .'.php';

    }

    spl_autoload_register('autoload');

?>
```

I hope somebody can help me and I'll understand it. Thank you.(Please don't say to me "I'm noob" if I did big stupid thing, I'm beginner and I'd like to learn it. )

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: Oh i forget it , sorry . This is the thing what i get when I run the index.php: " Fatal error: Class 'Person' not found in C:\wamp\www\oop\index.php on line 5"

Comment: There is a `;` missing after `private $age`.

Comment: Did you try writing everything into one file (e.g. index.php) for testing, first? You can always separate the code into different files when that is working as expected.

Comment: Try to change `include 'classes/'.$class .'.php';` in `include __DIR__.'/'.$class .'.php';`, if `Person.php` is in `classes` directory.

Comment: I improved it ,but the problem is same.

Comment: Windows shouldn't be the problem, but one time you write "Autoload" and the other time "autoload".

Comment: Can you add to your question your directory structure?

Comment: do you mean this: www/oop/classes  and in oop folder has index.php more php files have in classes folder

Comment: Have you tried to use absolute path when you include the class, as I suggest before? Can you edit the question with the updated `autoload.php`? Did you get other php errors?

Comment: I tried now that i took all file same foledr , but i get again same error. "Fatal error: Class 'Person' not found in C:\wamp\www\oop\index.php on line 5" (I begin give up the oop php )

Comment: ^ Can you edit the question with the updated `autoload.php`?

Comment: the post has been edited

Comment: You do not understand the post of Marc B? Here is the documentation: http://php.net/manual/it/language.oop5.autoload.php

Answer (score 2):

it's `__autoload` (**TWO** underscores). you have `_autoload` (**ONE** underscore):

```
function _autoload($class){
         ^---
```

Comment: uhm, more than advise this, I will suggest to edit `spl_autoload_register('autoload');` in `spl_autoload_register('_autoload');`

Comment: I tried it , but the code still wrong. I can't imagine what is wrong. I've rewritten the all code and i get same problem again. I don't know that is matter , but i use wamp server and Sublime text